# Sorting columns containing exponents in python

Tags: python, sorting, exponent

I have created `mylist` that reads out:

```
[('GCK', '3e-12'), ('ist', '6e-30'), ('iso', '5e-15'), ('tig', '5e-77')]
```

when I run the sort function:

```
mylist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

it sorts the list on the 2nd column, but only by the 1st integer

```
[('GCKDGN101ANI4S', '3e-12'), ('isotig13037', '5e-15'), ('isotig14607', '5e-77'), ('isotig03156', '6e-30')]
```

How do I get it to sort by the entire number in the 2nd column so that the order is:

```
[('GCK', '3e-12'), ('ist', '5e-15'), ('tig', '6e-30'), ('iso', '5e-77')]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'3e-12'` is not a number, it is a string. String are sorted by each letter.

You want to sort numbers so you have to convert them first. Either in the original data:

```
old = [('GCK', '3e-12'), ('ist', '6e-30'), ('iso', '5e-15'), ('tig', '5e-77')]
new = [(name, float(x)) for name,x in old]
new.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

or convert the items during sorting:

```
old.sort(key=lambda elem: float(elem[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = [('GCK', '3e-12'), ('ist', '6e-30'), ('iso', '5e-15'), ('tig', '5e-77')]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)
[('GCK', '3e-12'), ('iso', '5e-15'), ('ist', '6e-30'), ('tig', '5e-77')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add float conversion:

```
>>> mylist.sort(key=lambda x:float(x[1]), reverse=True)
>>> mylist
[('GCK', '3e-12'), ('iso', '5e-15'), ('ist', '6e-30'), ('tig', '5e-77')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert strings to numbers first.

```
import operator

a = [('GCKDGN101ANI4S', '3e-12'), ('isotig13037', '5e-15'), ('isotig14607', '5e-77'), ('isotig03156', '6e-30')]
converted_a = [ (row[0],float(row[1])) for row in a ]
converted_a.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

print converted_a
```